# Overwrite prototype function in pick a date library

Tags: javascript, prototype, overwrite, pickadate

I want to change the default behavior of the `DatePicker.prototype.nodes.createYearLabel()` function in [picker.date.js](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/blob/master/lib/picker.date.js#L1091).

1. How can this be done without touching the orginal picker.date.js
   file?
2. How would my overwrite file have to look like? Do I need to
   import the picker.date.js somehow?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply overwrite the function anywhere in your code:

```
DatePicker.prototype.nodes.createYearLabel = function() {
     // code..
}
```

**However,** be careful that when you alter `DatePicker.prototype`, every instance of `DatePicker` created will be altered, **even those created before the change**. Keep this in mind:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.show = function(text) { console.log(text); };

var a = new A();
a.show("asdf");    // asdf

A.prototype.show = function(text) { console.log(text + "1234"); };
a.show("asdf");    // asdf1234
```

If you want to use your overwritten function in your entire app and do not require the default one, you may simply place it at **"the top"** of your code, that meaning before any of your code gets executed, but **after** the library is loaded.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This always returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: DatePicker is not defined`

Comment: @nimrod If you are using a bundler such as webpack, you may need to require your library before overwriting. However, you cannot persist your overwritten function, as everytime you require the library again, it will use the default one. Alternatively, you can do something like `window.DatePicker = DatePicker` after overwritting and simply use `window.DatePicker`, which is the equivalent of a global variable, instead of requiring.